# Xcode UML diagram

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, uml

I have an Xcode project written in Objective C and I am trying to create a UML diagram. However, the project is too big for me to create by hand so and I can't find the class modeling function in Xcode4. Is there a free UML program that I can import my xcode project and automatically generates the UML diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) should be able to draw UML diagram for your code.

Another option could be [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XIB files and you want to understand better an app inside Xcode you can look at the main.storyboard. [iOS Storyboards](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5055364-ios-storyboards-getting-started) this view helped me a lot.
[image: main.storyboard diagram]